# Преступление не нашло объяснения

Tags: грамотная-речь

подскажите, будьте добры, можно ли сказать "преступление не нашло объяснения"?

Answer (score -1):

Нет.

Преступление не может "находить". Можно изменить так:

Преступлению не нашли объяснений.

Лучше так:

*Нет мотивов для преступления.


Преступление осталось нераскрытым.*

Answer (score -1):

Вполне. Даже не вижу, в чем сомнения.
В нацкорпусе полно примеров с объектов объяснения в роли подлежащего или прямого дополнения. Вот навскидку - из классики и научной литературы.

> Александр Иванович припомнил все оттенки речи особы и нашел
>   все эти оттенки оттенками искренними; особа, наверное, не лгала; а
>   подозрения, ненависть ― все это могло найти объяснение в том
>   болезненном состоянии Александра Ивановича...

Андрей Белый

> Чинквеченто ― закат Возрождения. Это уже давно подмечено, описано, но
>   еще не нашло исчерпывающего объяснения.

А. К. Дживелегов. Очерки итальянского Возрождения

> Это ― закон термонейтральности, т. е. отсутствия теплового эффекта при
>   реакциях обменного разложения солей. Явление это, как известно, нашло
>   полное объяснение только после установления Аррениусом в 1887 г.
>   теории электролитической диссоциации.

А. Е. Арбузов. Краткий очерк развития органической химии в России (1948)

Впрочем, форм достаточно много.
Если судить по частоте, то предпочтительными будут такие (в порядке убывания частоты, оценка на глазок):

***Преступлению не нашли объяснения.***
***Преступление не нашло себе объяснения***
***Престулению не нашлось объяснения***
***Для преступления не нашлось объяснения***
и т. д.

Вариант ***Преступление не нашло объяснение*** - ближе к концу списка. Видимо, этот вариант тяготеет к научному стилю.

Comment: Про преступление так не говорят. Оно звучит стилистически ужасно. Нет таких примеров. "Не нашло объяснения" говорят про явление.

Comment: Где хоть один пример хотя бы даже в интернете, не говоря о книгах?

Comment: Скорее всего, это ваше личное мнение. Если выражение существует, это не значит, что его можно использовать где угодно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98421/discussion-between-behemothus-and-oleedd).